# rewrite htaccess to remove slug product

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some URLs like this:

```
https://example.com/product-name
```

I'll like to have `.htaccess` convert to SEO URLs in this way:

```
https://example.com/product/product-name
```

or otherwise.

This is how my `.htaccess` currently looks (it is placed in my root directory):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ product/$1 [L]
```

I've read and tried a lot of similar examples during the last 24 hours to no avail. I'm sure my server allows rewriting. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Is the word “product” just literal text? How are your URLs currently being routed? A URL like `/product-name` presumably already requires some URL rewriting to work? If you need to “convert for SEO” then you should presumably be redirecting the URL, not rewriting? However, your title asks to “remove” slug product, but your example appears to be adding it?!

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have old website with link https://mydomain/product-name, i need it's redirect to new website with link https://mydomain/product/product-name and "product" is category name. New website use wordpress cms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing WordPress directives. ie. Before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ /product/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This is a "redirect", not a "rewrite". Since you said this was for SEO.

Ultimately, this may need to be a 301 (permanent) redirect, but test thoroughly first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential cching issues.

The regex `^([\w-]+)$` is also more restrictive than in your example. Specifically, it excludes dots, so won't match actual files like `index.php`, but will still match `product-name`.